# scipy.optimize.newton Not Accepting "full_output" Option

Tags: python, scipy, scipy-optimize

Long time listener, first time caller here.
I'm relatively new to Python, but not totally hopeless. The code below works as long as I omit the full_output option.

```
from scipy import optimize
res = optimize.newton(calcdelta, currentstartcost, full_output=True)
```

But when full_output is included (either True or False), it spits out the following error:

TypeError: newton() got an unexpected keyword argument 'full_output'

It's not the end of the world, but any help would be appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: What version of scipy are you using?

Comment: According the `scipy` repository, the `full_output` parameter was added in May 2018.  I'm not sure which version that was.

Comment: My `scipy` version is 1.1.0

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I just needed to update.  I had to update `statsmodels` as well, as whatever version I was using would not work after updating `scipy`.  I had assumed everything would be current since I just started using Python a few months ago, but I guess not.

Thanks to [jakub](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5666087/jakub) for pointing me in the right direction